# AngularJS slider number binding not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am relatively new to AngularJS, and I am having trouble getting a slider and a number element to work correctly. When I change the number value, it updates the slider. However, when I change the slider value the number becomes invalid.

**HTML**

```
<div id="radius" ng-controller="RadiusController">
    <input type="range" ng-model="radius" ng-change="radiusChanged(radius)" ng-value="{{ radius }}" min="0" max="100" />
    <input type="number" ng-model="radius" ng-change="radiusChanged(radius)" ng-value="{{ radius | number }}" min="0" max="100" step="1" />
    Radius: <label>{{ radius }} km</label> 
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
angular.module("app").controller("RadiusController",
["$scope","RadiusService",
    function ($scope, RadiusService) {
        $scope.radius = RadiusService.getRadius();

        $scope.radiusChanged = function(radius){
            RadiusService.setRadius(+radius);
        }
    }]);
```

**Service**

```
angular.module("app").factory("RadiusService", function() {
    var radius = 10;

    return {
        setRadius: function(newRadius){
            console.log(typeof newRadius);
            radius = newRadius;
        },

        getRadius: function(){
            return radius;
        }
    }
});
```

I have checked the type is a number when setting a new radius, which it is. But when ever I use the slider the number element becomes invalid.

On the live site, when ever the number is changed it is has the following class:

```
class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-valid-number ng-valid-max ng-valid-min">
```

but when the slider is used it has this class:

```
class="ng-pristine ng-valid-max ng-valid-min ng-invalid ng-invalid-number">
```

The value attribute of the number will be the same as that of the slider, but nothing is displayed in the box. If you were to click to increment/decrement it would start from 0 regards of the number value attribute.

Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it by setting the $scope.radius in the controller:

**Controller**

```
angular.module("app").controller("RadiusController",
["$scope","RadiusService",
    function ($scope, RadiusService) {
        $scope.radius = RadiusService.getRadius();

        $scope.radiusChanged = function(radius){
            radius = +radius; //parse to integer
            $scope.radius = radius;
            RadiusService.setRadius(radius);
        }
    }]);
```